# two consecutive recursive call OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have the following function :

```
let extract n l =
    let rec aux acc pro = function
         |[]   -> acc
         |a::b -> if (List.length pro) = n then aux (pro::acc) [] (a::b) else aux acc (a::pro) b; aux acc (pro) b
    in aux [] [] l
```

As you can see in my pattern matching at the second test's case I am calling two times the function. Is it possible ?

So it is possible to have this kind of function :

```
let rec some_function = function
   | [] ->[]
   | a::b -> some_function b; some_function b (*so I am calling two times the function in a single test*)
```

I am asking this question because here I have the following warning :

```
File "main.ml", line 4, characters 48-72:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
```

So there is a problem at the exact place I called two times my recursive function. 
It might be because I am using `;` but in this case how could I seperate these two calls ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add onto FlorianWeimer's answer, some information about your error message.

```
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
```

OCaml is strongly typed. Therefore, if a function returns, say, an integer or a list, and you don't do anything with it, it'll wonder what's going on and warn you.

A function call like `print_int 5;` returns `()`, which is of type `unit`. That basically means that it returns nothing because you're not calling it to *compute* something, but to *do* something. It has done that thing and now it returns and you move on.

But a function call like `float_of_int 5;`, that returns a value (the float `5.0`). You (probably) didn't call it to *do* something, but to *compute* something, and what it returns is what interests you. Same goes for arithmetic expressions like `3+6;` or for straight up values like `10;` or `"abc";` or `[];`.

That's why, if you write one of these things that have a value and you don't use that value (in an assignment, or as a parameter of another function), OCaml warns you. It tells you "I computed something that I didn't assign, didn't return, and didn't use as the argument of something else. Usually, things of type `unit` are the only things like that. Are you sure you don't have a bug in your code?"

Sometimes you know what you're doing and you don't want that warning. In that case, you can call the `ignore` function. `ignore` will take anything and ignore it, returning `()`. For instance, `ignore 5;` or `ignore (float_of_int 10);` won't throw the "this expression should have type unit" warnings that you'd get with `5;` or `float_of_int 10;`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in the sense that the compiler accepts it, but it only makes sense if you do something with the result (or the function has a side effect).  The classic example for two function calls is the recursive computation of the Fibonacci sequence:

```
let rec fib = function
  | 0 -> 0
  | 1 -> 1
  | n -> fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```